# Jquery errors after CIVI upgrade to 5.46.3

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, mosaico, jquery

we are receiving jquery errors after upgrading to CIVI version 5.46.3 that is causing Mosaico not to load templates. I have manually readded the latest file for wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js and have also hooked it into the header to see if it might be a loading issue. Here are the errors thus far:
[image: errors]

Any suggestions would be great!